# SQL Server use PatIndex to find position of character, only knowing the start and end of pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to use patIndex to find a character position, only knowing the start and end of the pattern stored in a varchar?

I have tried using this but it returns '0' each time

```
select @emptyTag= patindex('<span%></span',@pmReportText)
```

Below is a small snippet from the varchar (`@pmReportText`), the position I want marked in red, the pattern is marked in green (and red for the first character)
[image: varchar snippet]

***Varchar Sample as Text:*** `<span style="font-size: 14pt;"><b><span style="font-size: 14pt;"><b><span style="font-size: 14pt;"><b><span style="font-size: 14pt;"><span style="font-size: 14pt;"></span>`

***Note:*** the reason I need to do this is to remove empty tags from db entries that got inserted due to a bug with RadEditor. There can be different length styles in the tag, this is why I don't know the length. I need to keep the RadEditor text styles otherwise I would just remove all HTML. The varchar contains over 128 levels so I can not use xml.

Comment: Please post the sample data as text instead of image..

Comment: I added the sample as text below the image

Comment: Why not just this `select charindex('><span',@str) as start_pos,
charindex('></span>',@str)+ 8 as end_pos`

Comment: This would properly be much faster to simply make a small console application in a programming language of your choice that pulls in the data and modifies it and saves it; which will provide you with more tools and logging and debugging capabilities.

Comment: Agree with @AllanS.Hansen. I don't know why you're storing and editing HTML inside of SQL, but strint manipulation is one place SQL falls short of most other approaches. Since you say you can't use XML (althought I don't follow exactly why), you could consider cleansing the data through a lightweight console app that uses a regex to replace the tags you don't want.

Comment: I had tried something similar to that @Prdp but `></span` will not necessarily mean the span is empty, for example there is some places where it is `<b></span>` The HTML in the db is a mess, personally I would just shred it all off keeping the lines and let the user restyle it but that is not an option.

Comment: I might take that approach Allan thank you,

Comment: Another approach I was just thinking of is you could use a string splitter function like one mentioned here: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings and then split on `'><'`. You could then self join that to itself and see when adjacent nodes are empty. You'd probably also need to keep track of the start/end indices of each tag, but the string splitters I mentioned already sort of do that. You could probably hack that into the function to return too.

Comment: @Xedni I am currently on placement bug fixing legacy code that is a mess, there is a lot of things that should not be done but are, The reason I started this in SQL  was originally I created a script to shred off all the HTML from the db entry keeping the layout but was then informed that this was not okay, The HTML is not correctly formatted so replicating the correct style is near imposible, so my intention was to remove all empty html tags and work from there. I will look at that link also, thanks

Comment: @Kevin gotcha. thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to get a string splitting routine, then split all of the text on the string '><'. This would give you a list of strings, which would be parseable with a much simpler set of code. As an example, assume that you put the output of the splitter into a temporary table #tmp (creative naming!). Then, let's write some parsing code, making no assumptions about the strings.

One important note first: When you use the string splitter this way, you should place a line break between the ending and starting characters (or after the splitting string if you use a single character string) instead of replacing them with a line break. This improves the efficiency of parsing code.

I am assuming that the temp table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (id int identity primary key, data varchar(max))
```

Code to identify empty spans would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM #tmp t1
INNER JOIN #tmp t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id - 1
WHERE t2.data LIKE '</Span>%'
    AND t1.data LIKE '%<Span%>' -- Is the startspan in this string?
    AND RIGHT(t1.data, 1) = '>' Is a tag at the end of the string
    -- Is there not another close tag after the last Span starts?
    AND (SUBSTRING(t1.data, Len(t1.data) - (CHARINDEX(REVERSE(t1.data), 'napS<') + 4, LEN(t1.data) NOT LIKE '%>%>'
```

Hopefully, this will help a bit.